# Is there any way to write a query to compare every record with few days before?

Tags: sql

Now I have a table "X" as below:

| uid | ---date--- | field A | val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-03-2021 | aaaaaaa | 103 |
| 2 | 01-03-2021 | bbbbbbb | 104 |
| 3 | 02-03-2021 | aaaaaaa | 106 |
| 4 | 02-03-2021 | bbbbbbb | 107 |
| 5 | 03-03-2021 | aaaaaaa | 109 |
| 6 | 03-03-2021 | bbbbbbb | 110 |
| 7 | 01-03-2021 | aaaaaaa | 111 |
| 8 | 01-03-2021 | bbbbbbb | 112 |
| 9 | 02-03-2021 | aaaaaaa | 113 |
| 10 | 02-03-2021 | bbbbbbb | 114 |
| 11 | 03-03-2021 | aaaaaaa | 115 |
| 12 | 03-03-2021 | bbbbbbb | 116 |

Is there any way to write a pure SQL to obtain a result to compare record with a certain offset, e.g.2days?

| uid | date | field A | val | prior-date | p-val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-03-2021 | aaaaaaa | 103 | 27-02-2021 | 0 |
| 2 | 01-03-2021 | bbbbbbb | 104 | 27-02-2021 | 0 |
| 3 | 02-03-2021 | aaaaaaa | 106 | 28-02-2021 | 0 |
| 4 | 02-03-2021 | bbbbbbb | 107 | 28-02-2021 | 0 |
| 5 | 03-03-2021 | aaaaaaa | 109 | 01-03-2021 | 103 |
| 6 | 03-03-2021 | bbbbbbb | 110 | 01-03-2021 | 104 |
| 7 | 04-03-2021 | aaaaaaa | 111 | 02-03-2021 | 106 |
| 8 | 04-03-2021 | bbbbbbb | 112 | 02-03-2021 | 107 |
| 9 | 05-03-2021 | aaaaaaa | 113 | 03-03-2021 | 109 |
| 10 | 05-03-2021 | bbbbbbb | 114 | 03-03-2021 | 110 |
| 11 | 06-03-2021 | aaaaaaa | 115 | 04-03-2021 | 111 |
| 12 | 06-03-2021 | bbbbbbb | 116 | 04-03-2021 | 112 |

Comment: Year 2020 dates in the table, but 2021 dates in the result?

Comment: Please mention your dbms with version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didnt get the pure sql part, if you mean to solve this problem without using window functions then you can just self-join

for example

```
select uid
      , A.date 
      , "field A"
      , A.val
      , B.date as prior-date
      ,  NVL(B.val, 0) as p-val 
from X as A LEFT JOIN JOIN X as B
    ON DATE_ADD(A.date, INTERVAL -2 day) = B.date
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: since no dbms was specified, i used mysql example, but postgres has DATEADD instead of DATE_ADD.

for oracle you can use the same syntax...

as long as the dbms has day interval addition/subtraction functionality, itll work with modification only to the last line. Rest of the code will work across all dbms

Comment: I have not confirmed the dbms but it really give me an idea on how to do it without programming on the result, thanks.

Comment: Remark (alternative for sqlite):
SELECT A.date, A.fieldA, A.val, B.date as prior_date, ifnull(B.val, 0) as prior_val, 
FROM X as A LEFT JOIN X as B
    ON date(A.date,'-7 day') = B.date AND A.fieldA = B.fieldA;

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports Lag() window function and there are always two rows for a date:

(It's for sql server. For other database `dateadd(day,-2,dates)` will be different.

```
 create table X(uid int, dates date,field_A varchar(50),    val int);
 insert into X values(1,  '03-01-2021', 'aaaaaaa',  103);
 insert into X values(2,     '03-01-2021',  'bbbbbbb',  104);
 insert into X values(3,     '03-02-2021',  'aaaaaaa',  106);
 insert into X values(4,     '03-02-2021',  'bbbbbbb',  107);
 insert into X values(5,     '03-03-2021',  'aaaaaaa',  109);
 insert into X values(6,     '03-03-2021',  'bbbbbbb',  110);
 insert into X values(7,     '03-04-2021',  'aaaaaaa',  111);
 insert into X values(8,     '03-04-2021',  'bbbbbbb',  112);
 insert into X values(9,     '03-05-2021',  'aaaaaaa',  113);
 insert into X values(10, '03-05-2021', 'bbbbbbb',  114);
 insert into X values(11, '03-06-2021', 'aaaaaaa',  115);
 insert into X values(12, '03-06-2021', 'bbbbbbb',  116);
```

Query:

```
 select uid,dates,field_A,val,dateadd(day,-2,dates)prior_date, 
 lag(val,4)over(order by dates) p_val
 from X
```

Output:

| uid | dates | field_A | val | prior_date | p_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-03-01 | aaaaaaa | 103 | 2021-02-27 | <emnull</em |
| 2 | 2021-03-01 | bbbbbbb | 104 | 2021-02-27 | <emnull</em |
| 3 | 2021-03-02 | aaaaaaa | 106 | 2021-02-28 | <emnull</em |
| 4 | 2021-03-02 | bbbbbbb | 107 | 2021-02-28 | <emnull</em |
| 5 | 2021-03-03 | aaaaaaa | 109 | 2021-03-01 | 103 |
| 6 | 2021-03-03 | bbbbbbb | 110 | 2021-03-01 | 104 |
| 7 | 2021-03-04 | aaaaaaa | 111 | 2021-03-02 | 106 |
| 8 | 2021-03-04 | bbbbbbb | 112 | 2021-03-02 | 107 |
| 9 | 2021-03-05 | aaaaaaa | 113 | 2021-03-03 | 109 |
| 10 | 2021-03-05 | bbbbbbb | 114 | 2021-03-03 | 110 |
| 11 | 2021-03-06 | aaaaaaa | 115 | 2021-03-04 | 111 |
| 12 | 2021-03-06 | bbbbbbb | 116 | 2021-03-04 | 112 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4739f4429be4061adce5935c4bf3912e)*